# Adding Multiple scripts to same GameObject in runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Greeting,

I was wondering is it possible to add multiple different scripts using array to same game object at the beginning of runtime.

This is a pseudo-code I think of:

```
public GameObject TargetObject;
public string[] ScriptsToAdd;

void Start(){
     for(int i = 0; i < ScriptsToAdd.Length; i++){
           TargetObject.addComponent<ScriptsToAdd[i]>();
     }
}
```

If I did something wrong here, please do let me know.

Comment: First, `AddComponent` instead of `addComponent`. Second, you need a type, not a string. It won't work imo. [adding-component](https://forum.unity.com/threads/add-a-custom-component-by-searching-for-its-name.323361/) - you need to get a type using its literal name.

Answer (score 1):

There some things you're doing wrong :

- first : use `AddComponent` instead of `addComponent`.
- second : you can't add string as component you use type for example `List<Type> components`.

Comment: The alternative that OP seems to want to use would be `AddComponent(string)` but agree one should prefer `AddComponent<TComponent>()` whenever possible